# related to out of memory in netbeans java

Tags: memory, netbeans

I am using Netbeans Ide and doing project related to Natural Language Processing.When Iam running my project it is showing error "out of memory".My training data(input file) size is 34 MB.I increased by heap size in netbeans.conf and project->properties->run VM arguments to 1024M.But it is showing same error.My RAM size is 1GB.I tried by setting vm arguments size differently like 1024m,768m etc....but not worked.
         In my project JNI code is used.From java programs C functions are called.Please give suggestion how to solve this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans comes with a profiler that can help you find memory leaks in your application.  Here is an article about how to use it.  http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html

Comment: I have run that project through profiler by setting VM args 512MB.In VM telemetry graph it was shown that max heap size as some 500MB and max heap used is 115MB. Yet it is showing out of memory error.

Comment: Thet's the way to start. Now you have to figure out why.